# c# вывести классы и их public и protected методы из dll

Tags: c#, dll, рефлексия

```cs
foreach (MethodInfo members in oType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
{
   //...
}
```

Имеется такое задание: "Функция должна возвращать имен а всех `public` и `protected` методов, которые содержатся в классах, находящихся в этих .NET сборках, сгруппированные по именам классов."

Этот код выводит полностью все методы, как сделать так чтобы выводились только `public` и `protected`?

Comment: Как думаете, почему `условие BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic` приводит к тому, что выводятся все методы?

Comment: Почему выводятся все я понимаю) к сожалению нет такого варианта BindingFlags.Protected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно отфильтровать методы по свойству [IsFamily](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.isfamily?view=netcore-3.1#System_Reflection_MethodBase_IsFamily), чтобы получить только `protected` методы

```
foreach (MethodInfo members in oType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
{
    if (members.IsFamily)
    {
        // Здесь делаете то, что нужно с protected методами
    }
}
```

Если нужны и `public`, и `protected` методы, то меняем условие:

```
if (members.IsFamily || members.IsPublic)
{
    // Здесь делаете то, что нужно с protected и public методами
}
```

Comment: Да то что нужно, спасибо